# How to select win/loss record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table "games" that looks like this

```
| team1_id | team2_id | team1_pts | team2_pts |

     1          3        101        117

     2          5        99         98
```

I would like to do select that gives back team name from table "team" and win/loss record like this

```
| team_name | win | loss 

   Boston     15   11        

   Miami      13   12
```

I figured out how to get table with number of wins only but have no idea how to get wins and losses in same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot and re-join:

```
select t.name, sum(is_win) as num_wins, sum(is_loss) as num_losses
from ((select (case when team1_pts > team2_pts then team1_id else team2_id end) as team_id,
              1 as is_win, 0 as is_loss
       from game g
      ) union all
      (select (case when team1_pts < team2_pts then team1_id else team2_id end) as team_id,
              0, 1
       from game g
      )
     ) g join
     teams t
     on t.team_id = g.team_id
group by t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should revisit your data model.  Maybe with `GAMES` table having fields `GAME_ID, TEAM_ID, POINTS`.  You can probably get it working with what you have so far, but its not ideal.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
select team_id ,
sum(case when Points > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Win,
sum(case when Points < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Loss

from
(
select team1_id as team_id , team1_pts - team2_pts as Points from games
union all
select team2_id, team2_pts - team1_pts as Points from games
)tbl
group by team_id
```